# EnumSet class, get element type at runtime

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I am trying to extend the https://github.com/tennaito/rsql-jpa library to support EnumSet fields.

I have everything working with regard to the actual query against the database, if I hardcode the ArgumentParser to convert EnumSet properties values to a specific query.

My issue is that given a query `enumsetfield=IN=(enumvalue)` the ArgumentParser gets a JavaType: `class java.util.EnumSet` and the string enumvalue.

How do I get the element type from the JavaType? I also have access to a `org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath` if that could possible contain the elementType.

Comment: Using reflection to get the generic type at runtime could be a solution. On the [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) thread there are some details about how this could be implemented

Comment: Yeah, I was almost going in that direction, but that would require me to replace the EnumSets everywhere in the solution, and custom mappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the information needed on the SingularAttributePath: `path.attribute.member.signature` which is in the form: `Ljava/util/EnumSet<Lmy.project.enum;>;` - this is not optimal, I had to rewrite the rsql-jpa a lot, and I ended up realizing that an IN query makes little sense with regard to comparing two collections. So the query now is `enumsetfield==enumvalue`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use reflection to obtain the non-public field in the `EnumSet` class that stores the element class. For example, for OpenJDK 8, [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/EnumSet.java) is the source code for `EnumSet`, and the field for the element class is called `elementType`. However, this would be implementation-specific to your class library implementation and not portable.

Comment: And while this is useful and used by many frameworks, it will break with JDK 16 (has given warnings earlier but now will throw exception).